# How to skip or ignore a config within j2 template if it's already in the running config (declared in a variable) of a Network Switch using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

running-config on the switch:

```
switch-1#
interface Ethernet1/1
  ip dhcp relay address 1.1.1.2
```

j2 template:

```
{% for ip in dhcp_servers %}
interface Ethernet1/1
  ip dhcp relay address {{ ip }}
{% endfor %}
```

variables defined:

```
dhcp_servers:
 - 1.1.1.2
 - 1.1.1.3
 - 1.1.1.4
```

expected config created with j2, later to be added on the switch:

```
interface Ethernet1/1
  ip dhcp relay address 1.1.1.3
  ip dhcp relay address 1.1.1.4
```

Only creating configs which are not present in the running config without needing to delete the ip from variable list (dhcp_servers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "running-config on the switch" parse the list of present DHCP servers. For example

```yaml
dhcp_servers_present: [1.1.1.2]
```

Then the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          interface Ethernet1/1
          {% for ip in dhcp_servers|difference(dhcp_servers_present) %}
            ip dhcp relay address {{ ip }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives the expected config

```yaml
  msg: |-
    interface Ethernet1/1
      ip dhcp relay address 1.1.1.3
      ip dhcp relay address 1.1.1.4
```